# share a videoview between two activity

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, fullscreen, android-videoview

my app there are two activities. first activity displays a videoview which plays a video in non-fullscreen mode(there are other info about the video which occupies the rest of the screen). also there is a button in the same screen which pressing that causes the video play in fullscreen mode.

the way I implemented full screen is that I start a new activity with a videoview and I send the url of the playing video to this new activity. then I can load the url from begining and so on....

Is there a way that I can reuse the same videoview of the the first activity in my second activity?

Comment: Do not user 2 activities, you need just animate your video view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, What do you mean animate my videoview?

Comment: Animate your just change layout parameters like width/height/x/y at runtime time to make it fullscreen + may be change system UI to make it real fullscreen as possible. You cannot transfer view to another activity. One thing I can think about is unbind from view and then bind it to another view in 2th activity. But really not sure, I did not do that before.